# Read multiple CSV file Python Pandas

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, pandas

I try to read multiple CSV files with different names in a directory (ex: Hello.csv, World.csv, ... ). And now I need to save the plot image in a different directory. This is my work

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import os as operating
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fonction to read files
def read_file(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename , header=None, delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]}, index_col='datetime', usecols=[0,1,2])
    df_New = df.rename(columns={2:'debit'})
    df_New_New = df_New.query('debit > 0')
    df_New_New.plot()

#change the directory path
operating.chdir('/home/user/Documents/try_folder/')

#list files name in a variable files_in_path
files_in_path = operating.listdir('/home/user/Documents/try_folder/')
```

in Ipython, this is the out put

```
In [6]: files_in_path = operating.listdir('/home/user/Documents/try_folder/')
In [7]: files_in_path
Out[7]:
['satro10.txt',
 'satro6.txt',
 'satro3.txt',
 'satro.txt',
 'satro9.txt',
 'satro7.txt',
 'satro2.txt',
 'satro8.txt',
 'satro4.txt',
 'satro5.txt']
```

And now I need to save a png image files of plot with

```
for i in files_in_path:
    read_file(i)
     plt.savefig(operating.path.splitext(operating.path.basename(i))[0] + '.png')
```

How to save the png in a different directory path?
Thanx

Comment: It's almost as if you are asking us to review your code here, does your code work OK? Also I don't see where `fixed_df` is defined

Comment: okey, don't give attention that I plot. I just want help, I post this comment because I have problem, the problem is that my work is not work

Comment: So you're saying it doesn't work? Which part? reading the csv, creating the df or the plotting? Does it work when it's just a single file?